# Spark 1.6.1 - Determining the number of clusters in a data set

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, clustering

There existis any way to find the number of cluster needed to use in K-Means?

I'm having some difficulties to find a method to determine k...

Many thanks!

Comment: see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/how-to-decide-on-the-correct-number-of-clusters), there is nothing implemented in spark that does it for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Elbow method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)